# Python: Rearranging an Equation to Take a Specific Form

Tags: python, sympy

Is it possible to ask python to rearrange an equation:
`-a2*b2*(c1 - 1)*(a2*c2 + 1) + (a2*c2 + λ + 1)*(a2*b2*(c1 - 1) + λ + 1)`

to the following form:
`λ**2 * ... + λ * ... + ...`

Would be great if possible, as I am trying to automate a calculation.

Comment: You tagged `sympy`, so have you tried to do this using `sympy`? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: I thought sympy would be where I might find such a function as I am looking for here. I am currently looking at "simplify" and its derivatives within sympy

Comment: Show what you've tried already in `sympy`.  You might also want to start with something simpler.

Comment: It is not an equation but an expression. Use ```expr.simplify()``` or ```expr.expand()``` the ```expr.collect()``` wrt lambda.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and post whether this is successful! :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
J=sym.expand(J)
J=sym.collect(J,λ)
```

This is the solution. Thanks to everyone who replied and particularly @cards for providing me with the correct solution!
Btw: J is the term/equation posted in the question, i.e.

```py
J=-a2*b2*(c1 - 1)*(a2*c2 + 1) + (a2*c2 + λ + 1)*(a2*b2*(c1 - 1) + λ + 1)
```